# gcloud deployment fails with BadFileExceptions

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I migrated an AppEngine project to Google Cloud Endpoints V2 and started using Google Cloud SDK and Maven for this project.

Unfortunately, deployment always fails. When `mvn appengine:deploy` is done, I get similar errors for (all) files that are uploaded:

**[INFO] GCLOUD: MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (class 'googlecloudsdk.calliope.exceptions.BadFileException', BadFileException('Cloud storage upload failure. Uploaded file does not match local
file: XXX\target\appengine-staging\__static__/scripts/modules.js. Please retry.',), traceback object at 0x0AE158A0)), last_retrial=3, time_pass
ed_ms=2522,time_to_wait=0**

I wonder why the uploaded files don't the match local files at my machine.

I retried it several times, but it always failed. Between the deploy attempts the target directory and the staging area in https://console.cloud.google.com/storage were deleted, but this did not help.

Development environment:

- Google Cloud SDK 218.0.0
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Apache Maven 3.5.4
- Maven project.build.sourceEncoding is UTF-8
- All files (modules.js for example) are UTF-8

Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appeared that the Project configuration in Eclipse was not up-to-date with the Maven pom.xml, after updating it and removing the staging area/bucket from https://console.cloud.google.com/storage, deployment went fine.

Note when this even fails: try to remove the staging areas from your local machine as well and deploy with Eclipse - Right mouse click on project - Deploy to App Engine Standard.